# WP encode post title into Percent-Encoding URL

Tags: wordpress, urlencode

I'm trying to covert post title into percent-encodeing. For example:

> nhà giả kim -> nh%C3%A0%20gi%E1%BA%A3%20kim

I found [this website](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) do exactly what I want but there is no guide to intergrate into Wordpress. Any help?

Comment: you ought to select @jaswrks answer, it does exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in PHP function [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) that can do this.

```
<?php
echo rawurlencode('nhà giả kim');
// nh%C3%A0%20gi%E1%BA%A3%20kim
```

*See also: [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)*